# Why making dnsmasq authoritative breaks CNAME resolution?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have a `CNAME` set up in dnsmasq as

```
cname=ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info,switch-3
```

It is resolved correctly (`switch-3` is a device which gets its IP via DHCP from dnsmasq):

```
root@rpi1 ~# host switch-3
switch-3 has address 10.200.0.123
root@rpi1 ~# host ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info
ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info is an alias for switch-3.
switch-3 has address 10.200.0.123
```

I then wanted to make dnsmasq authoritative for my domain by adding

```
auth-zone=swtk.info
auth-server=rpi1.swtk.info
auth-peer=192.168.0.13
```

Zone-transfer wise, it works: `192.168.0.13` can transfer the zone.

**But the resolution of `CNAME`s stopped.** I can still resolve `A` records (`switch-3` above for instance), `CNAME`s are not.

```
root@rpi1 ~# host switch-3
switch-3 has address 10.200.0.123
root@rpi1 ~# host ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info
Host ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

**What is the relationship between dnsmasq being authoritative and its abilty to resolve its `CNAME`s?**

<sup>*Note: this is an internal DNS, with no relationship with the `swtk.info` domain registered externally.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This behavior seems to be highly `dnsmasq`-specific, it's really not obvious how to follow this from a DNS perspective.
In my opinion it would be worthwhile considering setting up a "real" nameserver (at which point generally applicable understanding of DNS will be relevant, instead), but that will undoubtedly make for a less integrated setup.

I'm not a `dnsmasq` user myself, but it seems to me that the following section from the the [`dnsmasq` manual](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) explains its behavior and requirements in this scenario (emphasis added):

> **When dnsmasq is configured to act as an authoritative server, the
>   following data is used to populate the authoritative zone.**
>
> --mx-host, --srv-host, --dns-rr, --txt-record, --naptr-record, --caa-record, as long as the record names are in the authoritative domain.
>
> **--cname as long as the record name is in the authoritative domain. If the target of the CNAME is unqualified, then it is qualified with the
>   authoritative zone name.** CNAME used in this way (only) may be
>   wildcards, as in
>
> --cname=*.example.com,default.example.com
>   IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from /etc/hosts (and --addn-hosts ) and
>   --host-record and --interface-name provided the address falls into one of the subnets specified in the --auth-zone.
>
> **Addresses of DHCP leases, provided the address falls into one of the
>   subnets specified in the --auth-zone.** (If constructed DHCP ranges are
>   is use, which depend on the address dynamically assigned to an
>   interface, then the form of --auth-zone which defines subnets by the
>   dynamic address of an interface should be used to ensure this
>   condition is met.)
>
> **In the default mode, where a DHCP lease has an unqualified name, and
>   possibly a qualified name constructed using --domain then the name in
>   the authoritative zone is constructed from the unqualified name and
>   the zone's domain.** This may or may not equal that specified by
>   --domain. If --dhcp-fqdn is set, then the fully qualified names associated with DHCP leases are used, and must match the zone's
>   domain.

Ie, based on the above section of their manual, my understanding is that your `cname=ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info,switch-3` means `ch1-lampe-bureau.swtk.info. CNAME switch-3.swtk.info.`.

Additionally, it appears that names registered from DHCP are only added with names inside the auth zone if the `auth-zone=...` also specifies a subnet matching their assigned IP address. (as per `--auth-zone=<domain>[,<subnet>[/<prefix length>][,<subnet>[/<prefix length>].....][,exclude:<subnet>[/<prefix length>]].....]`)

So currently `switch-3.swtk.info.` probably does not exist, but if you specify the appropriate subnet for your zone that name should appear, at which point the `--cname` also should start working.